# Gmail compose FROM address based on TO address

Tags: gmail

Is there a script that would automatically change "From:" address according to a filter on "To:" address? E.g. I want all the messages sent to @domain.com to be sent from @yahoo.com, and the rest from my default gmail account. I know there is "reply from the same address..." option, but this is not what I want, I am interested in NEW messages only.

I know there was a script for this: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/71859 but it is no longer maintained and does not work after recent changes in gmail.